# developing a Visual Studio extension, how to get the root path of the folder view

Tags: visual-studio, sdk

In Visual Studio 2017 it possible to open a folder view instead of a Solution.

I need the path to search the folder.

Is there a property or specific class that I can use?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

To get solution directory you can use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(DTE.Solution.FileName)`